# List of language codes (ISO639-1) in Python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to get the list of all ISO639-1 language codes from pycountry 1.15? For example, ['en','it','el','fr',...]? If yes then how?

The following doesn't work I am afraid:

```
import pycountry
pycountry.languages
```

Comment: Do you want ISO 3166 country codes or ISO 639 language codes? As far as I know there is no such thing as a "ISO 3166-2 language code."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will give you a list of two-digit ISO3166-1 country codes:

```
countries = [country.alpha2 for country in pycountry.countries]
#countries = [country.alpha_2 for country in pycountry.countries]  # for python3
```

This will give you a list of two-digit ISO639-1 language codes:

```
langs = [lang.iso639_1_code
         for lang in pycountry.languages
         if hasattr(lang, 'iso639_1_code')]
```

This will give you a list of all of the language codes:

```
langs = [getattr(lang, 'iso639_1_code', None) or 
         getattr(lang, 'iso639_2T_code', None) or 
         getattr(lang, 'iso639_3_code') 
         for lang in pycountry.languages]
```

Comment: Nice. `langs = [(lang.iso639_1_code, lang.name) for...` could be used to generate data for a language selection widget. If it'd only run on app startup, than there's no need for hardcoding a list of languages or keeping a separate database table.

Comment: It's *alpha_2*, at least on Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

For Python3 its:

```
countries = [country.alpha_2 for country in pycountry.countries]
```

Comment: This doesn't contain every language code, seems to omit some that are not linked to specific countries. Example: wikipedia states that 'AA' is a valid language code for  the Afro-Asiatic language family, but this won't be a result here.