# Create another numpy.array in a pandas data based upon conditionals

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I have a dataframe df_a, with a numpy-array named 'Language'.  I want to create another numpy-array, LanguageCode, based upon Language and the Language codes associated with a Language.

````
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'Language':[['cantonese', 'japanese', 
                 'mandarin','american'],['mandarin','english'], 
                 ['american', 'mandarin','cantonese']]})```
````

df_a

```
     Language                                  LangugeCode
0   [cantonese, japanese, mandarin, american]  [zh_yue,ja,cmn,us]
1   [mandarin, english]                        [cmn,en]
2   [american, mandarin, cantonese]            [us,cmn,zh_yue'
```

Comment: The LanguageCode column is available in your df_a?

Comment: Where do you retrieve the language code? Using `pycountry` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773035)?

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that you have a dictionary to associate language and language code, and then used map.

Please, check if it helps you:

### Assumptions:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_a = pd.DataFrame({'Language':[['cantonese', 'japanese', 
                 'mandarin','american'],['mandarin','english'], 
                 ['american', 'mandarin','cantonese']]})

#this is the hypothetical dictionary
lang_codes = {'cantonese': 'zh_yue','japanese': 'ja', 'mandarin': 'cmn','american': 'us','english': 'en'}
```

### What you can do:

```
df_a['Language Code'] = [list(map(lambda x: lang_codes[x], row)) for row in df_a.Language]
```

### Checking:

```
#getting the numpy array format
language_code = np.array(df_a['Language Code'])

type(language_code)

numpy.ndarray
```

And your dataframe will be:

```
    Language                                    Language Code
0   [cantonese, japanese, mandarin, american]   [zh_yue, ja, cmn, us]
1   [mandarin, english]                         [cmn, en]
2   [american, mandarin, cantonese]             [us, cmn, zh_yue]
```

Comment: Yes, I have a list of matching code.  I will try this.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @JeffMagouirk, if this answer addresses your problem, please mark answer as accepted so community can read as a trusted solution. Thanks