# No localization support for language 'eng'

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

My python script does that:

```
File "/Users/andrea/Documents/corso_visioture/py_sql/singleton_DB.py", line 32, in __del__
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 539, in close
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1003, in cmd_quit
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 163, in send_plain
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/errors.py", line 186, in __init__
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/locales/__init__.py", line 58, in get_client_error
ImportError: No localization support for language 'eng'
```

I really don't know hot to fix that, I tried a lot of ways but I've no right solution.

I tried to write that:

```
from mysql.connector.locales.eng import client_error
```

but no way, same error.

In Windows it works, but not in macOs.

Comment: `eng` should be `en`.

Comment: TO check all country language code you can check this [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773035/list-of-language-codes-iso639-1-in-python#:~:text=This%20will%20give,in%20pycountry.languages%5D)

Comment: that is not my solution, the right version is 'eng' cause the terminal say that

Comment: Are you try to change `en`

Comment: ye i try right now, nothing..same error